# Redis Pub/Sub - ETL -> Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, redis, etl, apache-kafka-connect

I have a simple task:

1. Subscribe to messages on Redis channel
2. Transform message, e.g.

   HASH: `'<user_id>|<user_type>|<event_type>|...'`
   with items:
   `{ 'param_1': 'param_1_value', 'param_2': 'param_2_value', ... }`  into tabular form

| user_id | event_type | param_1 | param_2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <user_id> | <event_type> | cleaned(param_1_value) | cleaned(param_2_value) | ... |

3. Append to an existing table in Postgres

Additional context:

1. The scale of events is rather small
2. Refreshments must be done at most every ~15 minutes
3. Solution must be deployable on premises
4. Using something else as a queue than Redis is not an option

The best solution I came up with is to use Kafka, with Kafka Redis Source Connector (https://github.com/jaredpetersen/kafka-connect-redis) and then Kafka Postgres Sink Connector (https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink). It seems reasonable, but the task seems like generic Redis to Postgres ETL and I'm wondering if there is really no easier out of the box solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write a script and execute it via cron.  But take a look at the Benthos project as you can easily run it on prem and what you describe can be done entirely via configuration for Redis -> Postgres.

Comment: Thanks! Benthos seems exactly like the solution I was hoping to find. Weird I didn't know it before.

Comment: Yea I stumbled on it by accident myself.  Hope it works out.